# Who got warp drive when and how?

Tags: history, warp, transwarp, star-trek

What is the timeline for the acquisition or development of warp drive among the various major species of Star Trek (e.g. Humans, Vulcans, Bajorans, Cardassians, Romulans, Klingons etc.)?   If the means of achievement of various warp milestones is known,  this should be included to.

Comment: Hi. I note you haven't accepted any answers for this question yet. If my answer addresses the question, would you please consider answering it for future viewers? If not, please let me know where I can improve it!

Comment: Do [Bajoran lightships](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bajoran_lightship) count, or other faster-than-light spacecraft that lack a conventional warp drive?

Answer (score 12):

Because this got a little long, I'll cut to the chase and give you a list in chronological order - you can read the rest of the answer if you like for more details.  Note that I'm going to use the more conservative dates in this timeline; as you'll see below there are some more 'wild' guesses:

1. Vissians - 12th Century CE
2. Borg - 15th Century CE
3. Cardassians - 1925
4. Ferengi - after 1947
5. Vulcans - after 1947
6. Klingons - after 1947
7. Humans - 2063
8. Bajorans - 2328

---

Okay, so I'll start with the easiest:

## Humans

### When?

April 5th 2063

### How?

A guy called Zefram Cochrane decided he wanted to live the high life so he'd invent a great new space faring propulsion technique, get rich quick and have a cozy life.

---

Now, for the rest of them I'm relying on this brilliant [Memory Alpha article][1]

## Vulcans

### When?

Sometime *after* 1947 (*DS9*: 'Little Green Men').  Note that, out of canon, [Memory Beta][2] tells us that the Vulcans and Romulans had warp drive as early as the 3rd century CE, but later lost that technology.  This may explain how the Romulans traveled to Romulus from Vulcan [which is a reasonable distance][3].

### How?

Not much information on Vulcan warp-development is given; it seems that they slowly developed it under their own steam (*ENT*: 'First Flight')

## Klingons

### When?

Sometime after 1947 (*DS9*: 'Little Green Men')

### How?

The Memory Alpha article claims that they invented it.  Don't look at me so suspiciously: Quark's comments in 'Little Green Men' would suggest that Quark thinks the Klingons may have been responsible for the development of warp drive by themselves, as it implies it took them a long time to develop it.  Furthermore, the [Klingon page on Memory Alpha][4] says:

> Because the worlds of the Klingon Empire were resource-poor, the Klingons developed an intense belief in the need for expansion and conquest in order to survive.

This would *definitely* encourage developing warp drive by themselves.

## Vissians

### When?

Around the 12th Century (*ENT*: 'Cogenitor')

### How?

In the above episode, they claim that they developed it, so we'll have to assume for now that they made it by themselves!

## Borg

### When?

Unknown, but probably prior to the 15th century when they had begun to establish their interstellar collective (*VOY*: 'Dragon's Teeth').  [Out of canon][5], it seems they were Warp capable from the 46th Century BCE.

### How?

Because they had begun to establish their interstellar by the time they developed warp drive (ignoring non-canon materials for the moment), it's possible they simply assimilated or otherwise acquired the technology from a warp-capable passerby, or developed it themselves.  It's not really elaborated on much

## Ferengi

### When?

Sometime after 1947, as indicated by Quark's remark in *DS9*: 'Little Green Men'

### How?

We don't *strictly speaking* know, but it's probable that they bought it at some point.

## Bajorans

### When?

[Out of canon][6], apparently as late as 2328.  We know that they'd developed *sub-light* travel by the 16th century ([source][7]), but no mention of warp-capability in canon that I can find.

### How?

Well, if we assume the out of canon date of 2328, this happens to coincide with the date of Cardassian occupation, suggesting that they received it from the Cardassians!

## Cardassians

### When?

1925 from [out of canon][8] (no dates given in canon, but this seems reasonable)

### How?

No information here, probably developed it by themselves but that's just a wild stab in the dark!

Comment: You put an awful lot of stock in Quark's memory of history.

Comment: @Politank-Z well, beggars can't be choosers!  There's extremely little evidence other than Quark's memory of history so we have to accept it unless there is contrary evidence.  Otherwise this list would be much shorter!

Comment: Quark's line in "Little Green Men" when he ended up in 1947 was: *"Forget this timeline. The one we're going to create will be better. Once we get things in order here, we'll contact the Ferengi homeworld and sell them our ship. The Ferengi will have warp drive technology centuries before humans or Klingons or even the Vulcans. We'll establish an economic empire beyond even Grand Nagus Zek's wildest dreams. And I'll control it all."* Since he was talking about *changing* the timeline by giving the Ferengi warp drive, doesn't this mean in the actual timeline they didn't have it in 1947?

Comment: Also, did you mean to cite "Little Green Men" when you said the Vulcans developed warp after 1947, or was this also mentioned in the *Enterprise* episode "Fallen Hero" that you cited? [Here](http://www.chakoteya.net/Enterprise/23.htm) is a transcript, I did a keyword search and didn't see 1947 mentioned.

Comment: @Hypnosifl ah; I see what you mean about the Ferengi; consider it fixed.  And yes; must have made a typo when referring to 'Fallen Hero' - a lot of episodes flying about in that answer above!

Comment: In the delta flier episodes of DS9, the ciscos talked about the bajorans visiting the cardassians far earlier than the cardassians had warp drive. Given the distances involved and the delat flier entering warp, you might need to adjust your dates.

Comment: @The Doc - I see you fixed the initial list of dates, but don't forget to also fix the section on the Ferengi saying they got it "sometime prior" to 1947 (as well as the part saying they purchased it, since it was Quark's plan to sell it but he never got to carry it out, and we don't know how they got it in the actual timeline)

Comment: @Hypnosifl I owe you one again!  fixed :D

Comment: @atk there is no indication in canon, to the best of my knowledge, that the Bajorans developed warp drive under their own power.  From memory, those episodes were referring to the discovery of a Bajoran *solar sailer* on Cardassia; that's a sub-light vessel, not a warp-capable vessel.

Comment: @TheDoc, i was under the impression that the solar sailer went to warp speeds... i may be misremembering, though

Comment: @atk seems we both misremembered: "Although lightships weren't capable of achieving warp speeds by design, a semi-controlled warp jump was possible if particles that were moving faster than light, for example tachyons, were to collide with the sails. However because the ship wasn't designed to endure the stress of warp speeds, it could be severely damaged as a result. It was thanks to such an uncontrolled warp jump that the ancient Bajorans were able to bypass the Denorios belt and reach the Cardassian system before they crashed on Cardassia Prime. (DS9: "Explorers")"

Comment: @atk so technically, the lightship *wasn't* a warp vessel

Comment: @TheDoc nice find! Agreed, not a warp vessel, even though it could fall into warp under certain circumstances

Comment: Just noticed that the memory beta article on Cardassians doesn't actually give any source for the claim that the Cardassians became warp-capable in 1925, so I think that should be taken as pretty questionable--see the comment I added to [the article's talk page](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Cardassian), where I also mentioned that the [Cardassian history](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Cardassian_history) article says in the "Cardassian Union" section that they became warp capable in 1670.

Comment: Also, I see that the ["Trivia" section of the "Little Green Men" article on memory alpha](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Little_Green_Men_(episode)#Trivia) has a long paragraph at the end discussing evidence that Quark's statement may have been inaccurate, showing that both Vulcans and Klingons at least has interstellar travel well before 1947 (though as you suggest, it's possible they lost the technology and regained it after 1947...still, Quark's statement that the Ferengi could beat them by "centuries" was wrong since the *ENT* ep "Carbon Creek" showed Vulcans with warp in the 1957).

Comment: @Hypnosifl although regarding Carbon Creek we're not sure that actually happened!  Although seeing as though Archer and Tucker didn't point out that as a problem we're left in the dark!

Comment: A comment on Klingon culture - if Kahless pointed at a star and said he would return there they likely was a strongest motivator.  Though implicitly the Hur'q invasion established in DS9 would be a good motivator and possible source of technology.  Imagine where Earth's space program would be if Jesus has said what Kahless did.